# PhoneGap install on Mac

Tags: android, cordova

I'm getting a bit annoyed at this install. I've followed the instructions from [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) and I've got as far as adding Android as a platform, the large chunk of code is a copy and paste from my Terminal when I am trying to run it. I have Android SDK installed at `~/Development/sdk/` `~ is the home directory for the user`

```
Donalds-MacBook-Air:hello donaldsutherland$ cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

/Users/donaldsutherland/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
    at /Users/donaldsutherland/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:85:29
    at _rejected (/Users/donaldsutherland/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /Users/donaldsutherland/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/Users/donaldsutherland/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/donaldsutherland/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /Users/donaldsutherland/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Users/donaldsutherland/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: /Users/donaldsutherland/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
Donalds-MacBook-Air:hello donaldsutherland$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/your-path/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/your-path/android-sdk-linux/tools:/Development/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-linux/tools:/Development/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/sdk/tools
Donalds-MacBook-Air:hello donaldsutherland$
```

If I run `$ cordova platforms ls` it lists `Available platforms: amazon-fireos, android, blackberry10, firefoxos, ios`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a a profile file `~/.bash_profile`

write this line to add the android SDK folder to your PATH

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Development/sdk/tools:~/Development/sdk/platform-tools
```

close the terminal and open it again, then it should recognize the "android" command everywhere

Comment: Still getting the same original error. This PhoneGap Documentation is terrible. I've found so many variations of even creating an application and I'm stuck with the same error

Comment: `android` opens up the android sdk, but what I'm trying to do is `$ cordova platform add android` add to the application Im trying to set up which always comes back as the original error

Comment: I know, but your problem is that the "android" command isn't recognized when you execute the "cordova platform add android", when you execute that, the android command is executed internally and you have to set the PATH as I told you

Comment: Ok now Im getting the result `executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.`

Comment: If you are using Mavericks, ant isn't preinstalled, you have to install ant and maybe add it to the PATH

Comment: Thanks I got it through http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/setting-up-os-x-mavericks-and-homebrew/